# Change shipping and billing address from order programmatically

Tags: orders, shipping-address, programmatically, billing-address

How can i change shipping and billing adress from order programmatically?
I tried this but don't work.

```
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setFirstname("value")
->setMiddlename("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setSuffix("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value"))
->setCity("value")
->setCountry_id("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setRegion_id("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")
->setFax("value");
```

and

```
$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate');
```

Comment: is order address already exits?

Comment: yes, the order already exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want update shipping address of an order then you need load order then  load it address object:

**Step1:**`Order load by orded id`

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

**Step2:**`Get shipping address Id.`

```
$order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
```

**Step3:**`Then reset shipping address object:`

```
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId());

$shippingAddress
->setFirstname("value")
->setMiddlename("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setSuffix("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value"))
->setCity("value")
->setCountry_id("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setRegion_id("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")
->setFax("value")->save();
```