# Magento does not save billing city programmatically

Tags: billing, programmatically

I have an external application and I have to update the billing and shipping details of an existing order. The problem is that the billing city doesn't get saved with the rest of the data. I'm using Magento 1.8.
The code was inspired by this thread: [Change shipping and billing address from order programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35054/change-shipping-and-billing-adress-from-order-programmatically)

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); 
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId()); 
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getBillingAddress()->getId());

$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setFirstname("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value"))
->setCity("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")->save();

$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setFirstname("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value"))
->setCity("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")->save();
```

Comment: Does it have to do with the fact that I don't add the Region_id value? If so, why does it save the shipping address and the billing address remains unchanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deni,you have already `loaded shipping Address and Billing address from order` So you  don't need create new `Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')` object You just need to edit address object

```
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId()); 
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getBillingAddress()->getId());

/* here i have edit exiting order shipping objects */
$shippingAddress ->
->setFirstname("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value"))
->setCity("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")->save();

$billingAddres
->setFirstname("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value"))
->setCity("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")->save();
```

**You need to add  ->setRegionId() for get region if you region id of this country**

Comment: My original code is working just fine, except it doesn't save the $billingAddres ->setCity("value"). Why does it save  everything else, but not that value? The shipping address city is saved just fine. Could be a bug in Magento?

Comment: $billingAddres ->setRegion("value") doesn't save. Sorry for the mistype. Your code is working the region.

Comment: $billingAddres ->setRegionId() use...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of your code snippet:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); 
$orderAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address');
$shippingAddress = $orderAddress->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId(); 
$billingAddress = $orderAddress->load($order->getBillingAddress()->getId();

$shippingAddress                                     /* = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address') */
->setFirstname("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value")
->setCity("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")->save();

$billingAddress                                      /* = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address') */
->setFirstname("value")
->setLastname("value")
->setCompany("value")
->setStreet("value")
->setCity("value")
->setRegion("value")
->setPostcode("value")
->setTelephone("value")->save();
```

Comment: I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object on this line:
$shippingAddress = $orderAddress->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId()); 
Also there's double )) on setStreet in your code.

Comment: Edited the code! Please try now!

Comment: My original code is working, except the Region doesn't save.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code, I also included a custom shipping and billing attribute in case someone needs it:

```
Mage::app('default');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($_POST['nr_comanda']);
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getShippingAddress()->getId()); 
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getBillingAddress()->getId());

$shippingAddress
->setCompany($_POST[''])    
->setFirstname($_POST[''])
->setLastname($_POST[''])
->setTelephone($_POST[''])
->setStreet($_POST[''])
->setCity($_POST[''])
->setRegion($_POST[''])
->setData('custom_attribute', '123')
->setPostcode($_POST[''])->save();

$billingAddress
->setCompany($_POST[''])    
->setFirstname($_POST[''])
->setLastname($_POST[''])
->setTelephone($_POST[''])  
->setStreet($_POST[''])
->setCity($_POST[''])
->setRegion($_POST[''])
->setData('custom_attribute', '123')
->setPostcode($_POST[''])->save();
```